# How to call javascript function on pressing enter in html

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started learning javascript and html and I have a form with a button to check whether the password that has been inputted is correct.

However, I want to make it so that when I press enter the password is checked instead of having to press the button.

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="check(this.form)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
function check(form){
    var test = form.password.value;
    if(test == "password"){
        alert("correct");
    }
    else{
        alert("Incorrect");
    }
}
```

Any help on my problem or any advice at all would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Don't check passwords at client-side! It's trivial for users to see them in the source code.

Comment: I'm aware of the problems with it but I don't know how to send it to another script to check the password

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {  //13 is enter key code
       check(form);  //pass form...call function
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a "submit" button and override the [form.onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) event to handle this. That way you only capture the Enter on the form or any input fields and not on the whole document.

#### EDIT - Example

The above example enhanced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return myFunction(this)">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction(form) {
        alert(form.fname.value);
        return false;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Notes:

1. See that I now do `onsubmit="return myFunction(this)"` to return the value that `myFunction()` returns
2. If `myFunction()` returns `false` the submit is canceled (not happening), if it returns true the form is submitted.

Comment: This is called [implicit submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you give me an example in code, i think i understand but i'm not sure how to do it

Comment: I just tried what you suggested but it still doesn't seem to work, Here what i wrote: '<form id="password" name="login" Onsubmit="check(this.form)">
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="textbox" />
</form>'

Comment: `this.form` -> `this` => `onsubmit=check(this)` You are already in the form tag so `this` refers to the form